# PHP operator not functioning with my script properly

Tags: php

I have a login script that will check if user is admin or testuser.  I wrote this to check if either of these for when I set my site to maintenance mode it will not allow anyone to login except admin and testuser. Issue is as it stands I can only have 1 user to make it work.  So either admin or testuser.  I want to have both.  I know and read up on PHP and or statements but this did not work with what I am trying.  This is very basic imo.

```
  if($user === false){
        $_SESSION['message'] = '<br /><div class="text-center alert alert-danger" role="alert">Your username is incorrect. Please try again</div>';
    } elseif ($username <> admin or $username != testuser){
      header('Location: /maint.php');
      exit;
    }
```

This works

```
  if($user === false){
        $_SESSION['message'] = '<br /><div class="text-center alert alert-danger" role="alert">Your username is incorrect. Please try again</div>';
    } elseif ($username <> admin){
      header('Location: /maint.php');
      exit;
    }
```

I even tried adding the pipes instead of or but that did to work.

```
  if($user === false){
        $_SESSION['message'] = '<br /><div class="text-center alert alert-danger" role="alert">Your username is incorrect. Please try again</div>';
    } elseif ($username <> admin || $username != davidm){
      header('Location: /maint.php');
      exit;
    }
```

If both are in the script it fails for both and am redirected to maint.php

Does anyone see my error here?

What I have tried:

````
    if($user === false){
        $_SESSION['message'] = '<br /><div class="text-center alert alert-danger" role="alert">Your username is incorrect. Please try again</div>';
    } elseif ($username != 'admin' || $username != 'testuser'){
      header('Location: /maint.php');
      exit;
    }

    if($user === false){
        $_SESSION['message'] = '<br /><div class="text-center alert alert- 
   danger" role="alert">Your username is incorrect. Please try again</div>';
    } elseif ($username != 'admin' or $username != 'testuser'){
      header('Location: /maint.php');
      exit;
    }

```
````

Comment: put  your admin and test user single or double quote like 'admin'

Comment: Condition must be written as `elseif($username != 'admin' || $username != 'testuser')`.

Comment: Tested taht already as well.  Still redirects me to main.php

Comment: Are you sure $username is filled?

Comment: yes. 100% I even echo it on the main page for testing.

Comment: It looks like you missed learning comparison [operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php).

Comment: it also works fine if i write it like this ```elseif ($username != 'admin' )```

Comment: @MarkusZeller I am very well versed in how to use an operator.  Thats basically PHP 101.  As you can see I have tried many operators.

Comment: Sorry, but never seen Code like `<>` combined with `or` in PHP for such cases. Totally mixed up logical and binary operators.

Comment: @MarkusZeller you can use <>, !=, <,>,><,==,===, =

Comment: ... shouldn't it just be `and` instead of `or`? **Any** value of `$username` is always going to be not "admin" *or* not "testuser". It can't be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a matter of operator, the error is in the logic.

```
if ($username != 'admin' || $username != 'testuser')
    header('Location: /maint.php');
```

means, if the username is not `admin`, or if the username is not `testuser`, then redirect. This sounds good, except that it will always redirect, because if the username is `admin` then it's not `testuser` and viceversa. You actually want:

```
if ($username != 'admin' && $username != 'testuser')
```

Comment: Now i feel like an idiot.  I missed that.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work: You had no qoutes around "amin" and "testuser". 
Inside an if statment with an AND or OR I always use extra () around each part. Its better for reading and helps making no mistakes.

```
if($user === false){
    $_SESSION['message'] = '<br /><div class="text-center alert alert-danger" 
        role="alert">Your username is incorrect. Please try again</div>';
} elseif ( ($username != "admin") or ($username != "testuser") ){
    header('Location: /maint.php');
    exit;
}
```